Can't activate my own gnome shell extension
I use this guide https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMyR5lJf7dU to install my own gnome shell extension on ubuntu 22.04 wayland GNOME Shell 42.9
I created a folder ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/example@example.com, in it I created extension.js and metadata.json
contents of metadata.json:
{
"description" : "my extension description",
"name" : "example",
"shell-version" : [
    "42.9"
],
"url" : "",
"uuid" : "example@example.com",
"version" : 1
}

contents of extension.js
Then I relogin
As a result, my extension is displayed in Extensions, but it is not active. How to enable it?


solved https://superuser.com/a/1734075
